# How to make multiple aggregations with slick without group by

Tags: sql, scala, slick

Maybe anybody tell me how I can aggregate multiple columns without `group by` using slick. I need something like this example (doesent't work)

```
val q = for {
  d <- documents
  dr <- documentRecords
  if d.accountMonthId inSetBind monthIds
  if d.documentType inSetBind DocumentType.currentDocuments
  if dr.documentId === d.id
  if dr.accountId === accountId
} yield (dr.map(dr => dr.debit,dr.credit).sum)

q.first
```

Sql query should look like:

`select sum(debit), sum(credit) from document join document_record  where blahblahbalh`

Comment: https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.2.0/sql-to-slick.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aggregate multiple columns without groupBy in Slick 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21414449/aggregate-multiple-columns-without-groupby-in-slick-2-0)

Answer (score -1):

you can look over (partition by)
http://www.midnightdba.com/Jen/2010/10/tip-over-and-partition-by/

Comment: Thanks for advice, but I know how to write it in SQL. The problem is in creating query using slick syntax